# Sending headers with server cached files

Tags: php, http, caching, header

The following script will:

1. Return a 304 Not Modified header if a client cached version of the file is current.
2. If not, then it will return a server cached version of the file if it is current.
3. If not, it will create the file, store a copy in server side cache, and return the file.

My problem is step 2: returning a server cached version of the file. As seen where I create the original file, I also send some headers to indicate the type of returned file and to allow the client to cache the file.  How do I send those same headers when returning a server cached version of the file?

Off topic and not related to this question, but any comments on how I name the cached file would be appreciated. `$cachefile = $root.'/ayb_cache/'.preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", '', basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));`

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$root=dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));
$filetime=filemtime(__FILE__);
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) && (@strtotime($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) == $filetime))
{
    header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', $filetime).' GMT', true, 304);
}
else
{
    //Not yet cached on client

    $cachefile = $root.'/ayb_cache/'.preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", '', basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
    $cachetime=60*60*24*14;

    if (file_exists($cachefile) && (time() - $cachetime < filemtime($cachefile)))
    {
        // Serve from the cache if it is younger than $cachetime
        include($cachefile);
        //echo "<!-- Cached ".date('jS F Y H:i', filemtime($cachefile))." -->";
        echo "/* Cached ".date('jS F Y H:i', filemtime($cachefile))." */";
    }

    else
    {
        //create new file
        ob_start();

        header( 'Content-type: text/javascript' ); //tell the browser we're returning JS
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Cache-Control: public, maxage='.$cachetime);
        header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+$cachetime) . ' GMT');
        header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime(__FILE__)).' GMT', true, 200);

        echo('alert("My Javascript");');

        $fp = fopen($cachefile, 'w'); // open the cache file for writing
        fwrite($fp, ob_get_contents()); // save the contents of output buffer to the file
        fclose($fp);
        ob_end_flush(); // Send the output to the browser
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code below include the `header();` calls before the `include($cachefile)` statement.

```
if (file_exists($cachefile) && (time() - $cachetime < filemtime($cachefile)))
{
    // Serve from the cache if it is younger than $cachetime
    include($cachefile);
    //echo "<!-- Cached ".date('jS F Y H:i', filemtime($cachefile))." -->";
    echo "/* Cached ".date('jS F Y H:i', filemtime($cachefile))." */";
}
```

Comment: Ha ha, Eactly.  I feel dumb. Got to wait 9 minutes to select this as the answer.  Any thoughts on how I named the cache file?

Comment: Some suggestions would be `cache.key.js` and key being a hash of (user_id, timestamp) @user1032531